# using bagging algorithm with multiple models

Tags: python, machine-learning, ensemble-learning

i am trying to built a model for LasVegasTripAdvisorReviews-Dataset
using bagging algorithm ,
i have an error (Multilabel and multi-output classification is not supported)
can you please help me and tell me how to solve the error )

regards
the attachment contain link to [lasvegas dataset](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Las+Vegas+Strip) LasVegasTripAdvisorReviews-Dataset

```
# Voting Ensemble for Classification
import pandas
from sklearn import model_selection
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression   

from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
from sklearn.svm import SVC
from sklearn.ensemble import VotingClassifier,GradientBoostingClassifier,AdaBoostClassifier,RandomForestClassifier

url = "h:/LasVegasTripAdvisorReviews-Dataset.csv"
names = ['User country','Nr. reviews','Nr. hotel reviews','Helpful votes','Period of stay','Traveler type','Pool','Gym','Tennis court','Spa','Casino','Free internet','Hotel name','Hotel stars','Nr. rooms','User continent','Member years','Review month','Review weekday','Score']
dataframe = pandas.read_csv(url, names=names)
array = dataframe.values
X = array[:,:]
Y = array[:,:]
seed = 7
kfold = model_selection.KFold(n_splits=10, random_state=seed)
# create the sub models
estimators = []
model1 = AdaBoostClassifier()
estimators.append(('AdaBoost', model1))
model2 = GradientBoostingClassifier()
estimators.append(('GradientBoosting', model2))
model3 = RandomForestClassifier()
estimators.append(('RandomForest', model3))
# create the ensemble model
ensemble = VotingClassifier(estimators)
results = model_selection.cross_val_score(ensemble, X, Y, cv=kfold)
print(results.mean())
```

Stacktrace:

---

```
NotImplementedError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-bda887b4022f> in <module>
     27 # create the ensemble model
     28 ensemble = VotingClassifier(estimators)
---> 29 results = model_selection.cross_val_score(ensemble, X, Y, cv=kfold)
     30 print(results.mean())

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_validation.py in cross_val_score(estimator, X, y, groups, scoring, cv, n_jobs, verbose, fit_params, pre_dispatch, error_score)
    400                                 fit_params=fit_params,
    401                                 pre_dispatch=pre_dispatch,
--> 402                                 error_score=error_score)
    403     return cv_results['test_score']
    404 
...
...
NotImplementedError: Multilabel and multi-output classification is not supported.
```

Comment: Please fix your code (including the indentation)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the line:

```
    X = array[:,:]
    Y = array[:,:]
```

Meaning that your **feature matrix (X)** and **target vector (Y)** are the same.

You need to chose **only one column** to be your **Y**.

For example, let's suppose your want your **last column** to be **Y**.

Then, you should change the above lines to this:

```
X = values[:,:-1]
Y = values[:,-1:]
```

This should solve the error you got. The error you have basically means: **I don't support more than one column in Y**.